# Obscure import GeoJSON to PostGIS by ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr

I import UTF-8 encoded GeoJSON files and get a different column value in PostgreSQL.

*Execution command one template is:*

```
 ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=127.0.0.1 dbname=db user=user
 port=5432 password=1" "file.geojson" -nln kk1
```

Examples:

1. GeoJSON file:

```
 ..."features": [ { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": 4420590,
 "NAME": "", "CAD_NUM": "05:19:000044" }, "geometry": { "type":
 "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ ...
```

In PostgreSQL column (cad_num) table value is:

> 05:19:44

2. Other GeoJSON file

```
 ..."features": [ { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": 4419016,
 "NAME": "", "CAD_NUM": "05:22:000024" }, "geometry": { "type":
 "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [...
```

In PostgreSQL column (cad_num) table value is:

> 05:22:000024

Why in the first case does the formatting of the initial value occur? And in the second not?

gdal: release-1900-x64-gdal-3-0-0-mapserver-7-4-0
postgis: postgis-bundle-pg11x64-setup-3.0.0-2

Comment: Your question title is about PostGIS, but your actual question is about a non-geometry type.  What is the type of the `cad_num` column?

Comment: Does every feature in your GeoJSON data has a value for "CAD_NUM", and does it always follow the same pattern with 2, 2, and 6 numbers? Run `ogrinfo -al -so` for your GeoJSON files and check the types of attribute fields. Do they differ?

Comment: cad_num is character varying

Comment: thanks user30184

....
CAD_NUM: Time (0.0)

why is time?
what to do in such a situation? 
I need it to be a text field!